# array in where clause ORACLE

Tags: arrays, database, oracle

Why I can't use this sentence in where clause.  When a give an input like array?

```
AND .. IN_ARRAY_CENTRAL(0) = '0' AND  ...
```

it gives me:

[Error] ORA-00936 (117: 39): PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: What is `IN_ARRAY_CENTRAL`? Is it a function, procedure, collection (table-type array), associative array, VARRAY, something else? Please edit your question to give a [MCVE] including all the necessary details to replicate your issue and a description of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Please review [the documentation on PL/SQL Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/collections.htm), and add more details to your question. Maybe post more of your code. Here's an example of how you can use a varray in a `WHERE` clause. Also note that PL/SQL varrays start with index 1, not 0.

```
declare
  type vc_array is VARRAY(5) of VARCHAR2(10);
  my_array vc_array;
  output_var VARCHAR2(10);
begin
  my_array := vc_array('0','1','2','3','4');
  select 'OK' into output_var from dual where my_array(1) = '0';
  dbms_output.put_line(output_var);
end;
/
```

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but the question is so unclear it is probably unanswerable. It should probably have been a comment instead of an answer.